# Is this custom PyTorch loss function differentiable

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, gradient, loss

I have a custom `forward` implementation for a PyTorch loss. The training works well. I've checked the `loss.grad_fn` and it is not `None`.
I'm trying to understand two things:

1. How this function can be differentiable since there is an `if`-`else` statement on the path from input to output?
2. Does the path from `gt` (ground truth input) to loss (output) need to be differentiable? or only the path from `pred` (prediction input)?

Here is the source code:

```
class FocalLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FocalLoss, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, pred, gt):
        pos_inds = gt.eq(1).float()
        neg_inds = gt.lt(1).float()
        neg_weights = torch.pow(1 - gt, 4)

        pos_loss = torch.log(pred) * torch.pow(1 - pred, 2) * pos_inds
        neg_loss = torch.log(1 - pred) * torch.pow(pred, 2) * neg_weights * neg_inds

        num_pos = pos_inds.float().sum()
        pos_loss_s = pos_loss.sum()
        neg_loss_s = neg_loss.sum()
        if num_pos == 0:
            loss = - neg_loss_s
        else:
            loss = - (pos_loss_s + neg_loss_s) / num_pos

        return loss
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` statement is not part of the computational graph. It is part of the code used to build this graph dynamically (i.e. the `forward` function) but it isn't in itself part of it. The principle to follow is to ask yourself whether you backtrack to the leaves of the graph (tensors that do not have parents in the graph, *i.e.* inputs, and parameters) using `grad_fn` callbacks of each node, backpropagating through the graph. The answer is you can only do so if each of the operators is differentiable: in programming terms, they implement a backward function operation (*a.k.a.* `grad_fn`).

1. In your example, whether `num_pos` is equal to `0` or not, the resulting loss tensor will depend on `neg_loss_s` alone or on `pos_loss_s` and `neg_loss_s`. However in either cases, the resulting `loss` tensor remains attached to the input `pred`:

   - *via* one way: the "`neg_loss_s`" node
   - ***or*** the other: the "`pos_loss_s`" and "`neg_loss_s`" nodes.

In your setup, either way, the operation is differentiable.

2. If `gt` is a ground-truth tensor then it doesn't require gradient and the operation from it to the final loss doesn't need to be differentiable. This is the case in your example where both `pos_inds`, and `neg_inds` are non-differientblae because they are boolean operators.

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch does *not* compute gradients w.r.t the loss function itself. PyTorch records the sequence of standard mathematical operations performed during the `forward` pass, such as log, exponentiation, multiplication, addition, etc., and computes their gradients w.r.t those *mathematical operations* when `backward()` is called. Thus, the presence of `if-else` conditions don't matter to PyTorch provided you use only the standard math operations to compute your loss.